# Single sample stats

Tags: statistics

I have individual values and want to test each values significance against a randomly generated dataset (20 values but could generate more if needed). What is the best statistical test to do this please? Thanks!

Comment: Is this related to any programming task? Can you provide more details on the expected output?

Comment: This is a statistics question that would be great on [stats stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but is probably off-topic here.